# "androidx.transition.TransitionSet cannot be cast to android.transition.Transition" after updating androidx lifecycle from 2.2.0-alpha03 to alpha04

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-transitions

There are a few other questions like this but all refer to Android Support library. I'm using the new androidx libraries instead.

After updating the androidx lifecycle dependency from 2.2.0-alpha03 to 2.2.0-alpha04, I get the following crash (on Android 9):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 12345
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.transition.TransitionSet cannot be cast to android.transition.Transition
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.setListenerForTransitionEnd(FragmentTransition.java:307)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:419)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:139)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2341)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.run(FragmentManager.java:422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7037)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Same problem with version 2.2.0-alpha05.

UPDATE: actually, it seems that androidx fragment 1.2.0-alpha03 is being pulled in, and that is causing the problem. When using fragment 1.2.0-alpha02, the crash does not occur.  The problematic cast is added here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1b07d07c5a5ca70bdddeab356e7f5175f60094d4%5E%21/#F4

This crash happens after calling:

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .remove(f)
    .commit()
```

And the only workaround I've found is to remove the exit transition:

```
f.exitTransition = Slide(gravity)
```

Note, the fragment f is of type: `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a bug. As far as I can see you can change `import androidx.transition.Fade` to `import android.transition.Fade` to workaround this issue for now.

Comment: @MDikkii I noticed that in alpha03 (and earlier), the exit transition was working (had no effect) anyway (but wasn't crashing), so I wonder if it's something wrong with that exitTransition

Comment: It is. In `FragmentTransition` from `fragment-1.2.0-alpha03` source there is something new (I've checked `fragment-1.2.0-alpha02` and I can't see anything like that) // It seems to be `android.transition.Transition` so androidx version can't be casted `((Transition) transition).addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener()(...)`

Comment: I can confirm that the crash does not happen with fragment-1.2.0-alpha02 but does happen with fragment-1.2.0-alpha03 (I've just edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the upcoming Fragment 1.2.0-beta01 release.

See the bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142056487

Comment: I just updated to beta01 and can confirm this has fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem running gradle
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:**1.2.5**"
and none of the above solutions worked for me
However, when I upgraded to **1.3.0-rc01** the issue disappeared